# virt-manager doesn't show list of local KVMs but virsh does

Tags: centos, virtualization, virt-manager, virsh

When I open virt-manager GUI it doesn't show list of KVMs but virsh does. how can fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try restarting you Machine. and see what's the result.

Answer (score 8):

Check the output of `virsh uri`. If it returns `qemu:///session`, but you're using a `qemu:///system` connection in Virt-Manager, you found the cause.

In order to fix it, you should either create a "QEMU/KVM user session" connection in virt-manager, or run `virsh define ~/.config/libvirt/qemu/<filename>.xml` **as root**. This will create the xml definition under `/etc/libvirt/qemu` which will then be picked up by virt-manager.

Comment: To add "QEMU/KVM user session" in virt-manager, click File > Add Connection..., under "Hypervisor" select "QEMU/KVM user session", check "Autoconnect", and click "Connect".

Answer (score 2):

If you see a connection for `localhost (QEMU)` listed, double click it.

If you don't see *any* connections listed, go to **File** > **Add Connection**, leave all the defaults set as they are, then click **Add**.

Comment: I see `localhost (QEMU)`, but double clicking only brings the details windows. I need to see VMs. Thanks

Comment: So it shows as `Connected` but you have no virtual machines listed? This would have been useful to know in the beginning.

Comment: Yes it's connected, and I have 5 VMs running but it doesn't show them, Thanks

Comment: some help please.

Comment: I can connect to virt-manager remotely and it works fine but locally there is problem

Answer (score 0):

Another issue could be causing this is that you are using the terminal by user different than the one being used by `virtmanager`, for example, if your virt manager is using `root` and you are using your machine's terminal with user `admin` without `sudo`, you will get different result, most probably empty list since the system never used your another user for VMs.