# VM does not show up in virt-manager, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: virtualization, centos6

I spun up a VM using `virsh create`, and I am able to see the VM in `virsh list`, however, when I run `virt-manager`, I am unable to see the VM in the GUI

I am trying to use virt-manager to access the VM console (`virsh console` does not work)

Does anybody have ideas how to troubleshoot this?

I found this: [virt-manager doesn't show list of local KVMs but virsh does](https://serverfault.com/questions/418509/virt-manager-doesnt-show-list-of-local-kvms-but-virsh-does) : but the question was never answered

EDIT: tried restarting libvirtd, still see the same thing. "grep libvirt /var/log/messages" does not show anything

EDIT2: spun up a second VM on second HV, the second VM shows up in virt-manager, but the first one doesn't. Very odd. Diffing the xml files dont show anything major, and the qemu commands look the same under ps

Comment: I am still not sure what happened, but I was able to work around this by running virt-manager on another box and connecting remotely

Comment: check the connection uri in virt-manager

Comment: One thing I've noticed is a difference between the output of `virsh list --all` and that of `sudo virsh list --all`. My virt-manager VMs show up with the latter, not the former. The converse is true of VMs created with `virtsh`/`virt-install`, when executed _without_ sudo.

Comment: Running with sudo solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by checking the logs on the virtualization server (grep for libvirt in /var/log/messages) and see if any messages point you towards a problem.

I've encountered issues before where virsh worked fine, but virt-manager behaved weirdly. Restarting libvirt on the virtualization server has always solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yeah. Admin 101 - look for errors first. Beforea asking because that is what you will be asked for anyway. Error logs are always a good idea to start at. +1.